# Math puzzle: 10 digit strings generations

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations, puzzle

There was a question in a math competition that I attended last year. At the end of competition, I realized that my answer was wrong for the question below and I have never been able to figure out how to solve it.

**Here is the question:**

You are asked to generate 10 digit strings using digits from 0 to 9 once each. Any four-digit substring used in a string cannot be used again.

What is the highest number of unique strings you can generate using these rules? (and I need the list of them)

Example:

If you use a string 0243697518 in your list, you can not generate strings contain 0243, 2436, 4369, 3697, 6975, 9751 and 7518

To solve the problem, I have written a c++ program, simply it scans all permutation of "0123456789" and add them into a solution list if 4 digit sub-strings of the code has not been used before. But the problem of my algorithm is that the size of solution list varies by depending on your starting point that you add into the list first. If I start adding into list from "0123456789", list ends up with 504 entries which is not the maximum asked. I really wonder how to solve this question, any help highly appreciated. I'm open to hear your mathematical solution or any algorithm suggestions to generate the list asked.

Histogram of random approach as suggested by Peter (min: 575, max: 606): 
[image]

Above algorithm tries to generate list asked by scanning all possible 10 digit strings in a random sequence. Histogram generated over 100K trials. Because all possible 10 digits strings needed to be scanned for each iterations are 10! = 3.6 million, each iterations takes 10 seconds on my pc to complete. I could try optimizing my algorithm more if I believed that there was really no deterministic solution for the question.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the string-theory tag is for.

Comment: What was the answer to the contest problem? Was it $720$?

Comment: @bof yes they said that 720 is the maximum and they have the list.

Comment: It couldn't be any **more** than $720$. To get $720$, you have to use every possible $4$-digit string.

Comment: This seems to be a kind of packing problem. Such problems usually are difficult to solve.

Comment: @bof At that time, it appeared to me as if using every possible 4 digits strings which are 10x9x8x7 = 5040 pieces in the list was not possible. And still I'm thinking that there is no way to combine all 4 digits strings perfectly without any loss. But they said that they have the list. So I wonder that how they get the list.

Comment: @Peter - I don't know about packing problem, only thing I can agree is that it is really hard to solve, at least for me. During last two weeks I have studied graph theory, a lot of algorithms and ideas new to me came but still I have nothing.

Comment: Did you try to generate the sequences randomly ? Or did you use another approach ?

Comment: I didn't try randomly but I have tried different approaches such as that instead of scanning all permutations of 10 digits, I've created all possible 4 digit sub-strings and tried to combine 7 of them to make 10 digit string. What I've reached so far is 633. I've also seen the question as a graph and searched for Hamiltonian path but no chance. I'll try your random approach and let you know the result.

Comment: Perhaps, the naive approach (choosing randomly) produces a solution in reasonable time. Simply try it.

Comment: Another approach might be : genetic algorithms. But I have no idea how to improve a given solution.

Comment: @Peter - Random solution yields maximum 600 as list size. See histogram in the question. It takes long time to iterate.

Comment: How many trials did you make ?

Comment: @Peter - Around 600. Each iterations takes 10 seconds because it scans 10! inside.

Comment: Why do you need so many checks in the scan ? Simply delete the used digit-combinations and build up a number using the remaining. The best should be to use an array to store the combinations.

Comment: @Peter - Also I've tried obtaining each 10 digit strings from all possible 4 digit sub-string list randomly. This was faster but as maximum list size it reached only 103 over 1000 iterations. If you have another way, please describe your algorithm clearly. As a matter of fact, I prefer deterministic solution rather than a heuristic search.

Comment: @MehmetFide : I don't see how different starting strings would lead to different results. If you have a list of "the answer", you can always rename the digits 1<->something else, 2<->something else, etc, everywhere in the list and it will still be a solution. It doesn't matter what the digits are called. If a substring of 4 digits does not appear in other words initially, then it won't appear if you change the name of the digits everywhere either. So it must be something wrong with the implementation of your algorithm.

Comment: Not quite practical as a computational solution, but this can be reduced to the independent set problem on a graph of $10!$ nodes and $\frac{10! 7!}{2}$ edges.

Comment: @PeterTaylor - If I represented the question in a graph in your way, how could I find the list? It is not a shortest path or cycle problem in your case. I've tried graph but with a different approach. I've created nodes for each 4 digit strings which are totally 5040 pcs. And created directed edges between nodes if last 3 digit of source node is same as first 3 digit of destination such as 0123 -> 1234 or 5678 -> 6780. That way calculating Hamiltonian path would do the list but it didn't work because 7 nodes had to be unique in the sequence after combining all of them while they were not.

Comment: [Independent set problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory))

Comment: Have you studied the problem of $m$-digit strings without reusing any $n$-digit string for pairs $(m,n)$ smaller than $(10,4)$?

Comment: @MichaelJoyce - No I haven't tried it. What kind of benefit would you expect?

Comment: Well if it is true that you can get the maximum number of strings possible for $(10,4)$, that property might hold for smaller pairs as well.  Ideally, one might construct a proof of that property in the smaller cases that are easier to work with, and then find a way to generalize that proof to cover the case $(10,4)$.

Comment: I'm not sure, if I did understand your question correctly. Am I right, that you are asking for the maximum size of a set $\mathcal{A}$ containing solely strings of length 10, whereby each string contains all digits from 0 to 9 and whenever a 4-digit substring is part of an element in $\mathcal{A}$ it is not a substring in one of the other elements?

Comment: @MarkusScheuer - yes, all your sentences are correct.

Comment: The size of your solution should _not_ vary with your starting permutation - though it does vary with how you scan through the rest of the permutations from there.  If you started with, e.g., 4301598267, then you can just write A=4, B=3, C=0, D=1, etc., and easily map every value in your solution back onto another attempt where the initial permutation was ABCDEFGHIJ.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki - I see exactly way of your thinking. But it is not the case. Imagine there are numbers should be in your list and there are numbers should not be in your list. What would happen if you mixed them in the same list?

Comment: If we relax the "have to be permutation of 0...9", then this can be solved using de Bruijn sequence. Maybe we can use the de Bruijn's graph to help somehow?

Answer (score 3):

The [de Bruijn sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) gives you approximately 1428 possibilities (10000/7 plus or minus one or two due to rounding): shift a window of size 10 through it, each time shifting by 3 positions.

**Edit** (sorry, I also missed the part that you want permutations). This might bring you a bit closer to what you need: ["Universal cycles of k-subsets and k-permutations" by B.W. Jackson](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9390330V), and also look for newer papers and books citing this paper (for example, in Google scholar). By building an Eulerian walk in a suitable graph you can generate a cycle containing each partial 4-permutation exactly once, something called a universal cycle (ucycle) of partial permutations.

Comment: This allows repetition of digits; the OP does not.

Comment: I don't know where that 10000 comes from. But I had tried both De Bruijn and Kautz sequences similar to each other before. B(4, 10) generates unique sequence of 4 digits. When I combine them in order to generate 10 digits, characters inside are not being unique anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating between 10-digit numbers, make a list of all the possible 4-digit numbers (which are $10*9*8*7=5040$ and merge 7 4-digit numbers at a time to obtain 10-digit numbers. It is a dynamic programming question and you will have to backtrack to get already used 4-digit numbers into 10-digit numbers that require them the most. Using this approach, the maximum possible 10-digit strings should be $(10*9*8*7)/7=720$.

Comment: Well the problem here is that each digits are unique. So it is not 10000, it is 10x9x8x7=5040. I've heard about algorithms you mentioned, but I don't have any practical abilities on them. I need to study.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the part that digits are unique within a string. I've edited my answer.

Comment: You should edit "..merge 7 4-digit numbers at a time to obtain 10-digit numbers" section as well. Because it is not easy to merge 4-digit numbers anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution but here are some thoughts on the problem. We can look at the $(m,n)$ of finding the maximum possible number of strings of $m$ symbols with no strings of length $n$ used more than once in the whole set of strings. We can construct a graph $G$ whose vertices $V$ are the $n$-digit strings. We'll put an edge between two vertices $v$ and $v'$ if the strings overlap in the following way

$$v = s_1 s_2 \ldots s_n, \quad v' = s_2 \ldots s_n s_{n+1}$$

where $s_1 \neq s_{n+1}$. We connect every vertex $v$ to $m-n$ other vertices. Also every vertex has $m-n$ edges leading to it. Overall

$$|V| = n!\binom{m}{n} = \frac{m!}{(m-n)!},\quad |E| = (m-n)|V| = \frac{m!}{(m-n-1)!}$$

We can represent each $m$-digit string by a directed path in $G$ of length $m-n$, containing $m-n+1$ vertices. We need to find the maximum number of such vertex-disjoint paths in $G$. One would have a theoretical maximum of

$$\frac{m!}{(m-n+1)!}$$

such paths if all the vertices are used. In your case of $m = 10$, $n = 4$ you have 720 possible paths and from the problem you know you can find this many paths. This corresponds to finding a vertex cover of $G$ consisting of paths of vertex length 7. If anyone knows of an algorithm to find such a cover, then they can apply it to this problem. This is not always the case though. For $m = 3$ and $n = 2$ you'd expect $6/2 = 3$ such paths but the graph $G$ consists of 2 disjoint directed 3-cycles.

Clearly, the graph $G$ has to remain invariant by any permutation of the digits themselves, so one could easily set one of the paths in the cover as $0123\to 1234 \to \cdots \to 6789$.

Another thing to note is that if we can find a Hamiltonian cycle in the graph we can delete every $m-n+1$-th edge to obtain such a maximal cover if one exists. Unfortunately I don't have an algorithm for finding Hamiltonian cycles in a directed graph but someone else might.

Comment: Here is the hamiltanian cycle for the graph has 5040 vertices: ( http://files.figshare.com/1780575/Hamiltonian_Cycle.txt ) A means 0, B means 1, etc.. But it doesn't help because when you merge them, you will find repeating digits in combined 10 digit strings. So solution way should be something else.

Comment: You mean there are repeating 4-digit strings?

Comment: Ahh, you don't have the right graph. From the start you have BCDA, CDAB where B repeats. In my graph I've put the edges only when the first digit of the first vertex is not the same as the last digit of the end vertex. The resulting graph is sparser than what you will get if you only put edges for the overlaps.

Comment: For example this is the part of cycle found. "1230 -> 2301 -> 3014 -> 0143 -> 1430 -> 4305 -> 3054 -> 0543 -> 5436 -> 4365 -> 3654 -> 6542.." Lets combine them to make 10 digits: 123014305436542... See first 10 digit after merging them, there are not unique. They are uniqe only in 4 digits window.

Comment: Did you see my response? Could you try this with the modified graph?

Comment: I see your point. I'll try that too. But It seems that S1 != Sn+1 condition is not sufficient as well. S1 and Sn+1 of 10 consecutive vertices in the Hamiltonian cycle should not be same. For example 0123 -> 1239 -> 2398 -> 3985 -> 9852.. will fit into your conditions but not to the question because '2' has used at the beginning.

Comment: I see your point. That's true.